# Disable drag and drop option for multiple file uploader

Tags: development, jquery

These are the screenshots of multiple file uploader from the same SharePoint 2010 site. Some users are seeing the first and some are seeing the second one. Is it possible to disable the second view(drag and drop) by editing upload.aspx in the layouts folder?

[image]

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the multiple uploading function is controlled by the "STSUPLD.DLL" addon which you can find in Internet Explorer and you have the following options:

1. If you remove the add-on and restart your browser, the multiple upload option is disabled.
2. If you have Office 2007 installed (this is where the dll is actually located) you get the checkboxes
3. If you have Office 2010 installed, you get the normal drag 'n drop

I advise against changing the upload.aspx file and/or this dll file, as you are actually trying to enable the older version. However, you perform an experiment by copying the dll from a computer with Office 2007 to the correct location ("%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Office14\") of a computer with Office 2010 installed, to see if this will have the desired result.

You can of course modify the upload.aspx file (backup the original first) and I am sure you will find many resource online, or event complete projects, but us you will soon notice, pleople actually want to do the opposite. That is, to enable drag n drop functionality when this is not available.